# Prediction failed: unknown error

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I'm using Google Cloud Machine Learning to predict images with labels.
I've trained my model, named flower and I see the API end point at Google API Exporer but, when I call the API at API Explorer, I get the following error:

[Image Error](https://webappbrasil.blob.core.windows.net/teste/Captura%20de%20Tela%202017-06-16%20a%CC%80s%2012.00.26.png)

I can't understanding why.

Thanks

Ibere

Comment: Our apologies for the problem and unhelpful error message. If you're willing to let us look into your logs, etc. to help, please send your project/model/version name to cloudml-feedback@ and reference this post.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you followed the tutorial from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers?

I had the exact same problem but with some trial and errors I succeeded with the payload:

```
{"instances":[{"image_bytes": {"b64": "/9j/4AAQ...rest of the base64..."}, "key": "0"}]}
```

Comment: After spending 2 hours debugging, your solution fixed this issue. Thanks